# How to htmlencode body but not heading of gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView. I want the content of the cells, the actual detail data, to be html-encoded. But I want to keep the raw HTML in the heading.

That is, the heading in this case is the name of a language and the ISO code, for example "English (EN)". I want the name and code on separate lines, so I'm specifying the heading as "English<br/>(EN)".

But for the content, I want to see any HTML. If it says "<p>foobar</p>" I want the p-tags to display.

If I say "htmlencode=false", then the heading doesn't get encoded, but neither does the data.

Is there any way to say, html-encode the data, but not the heading?

If it matters, I'm building the columns in code rather than with tags in the ASP file, depending on which languages I find in my data. So here's how I'm creating the column:

```
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim iso2 = row("language")
    Dim name = row("name")
    ... other code ...
    Dim head = String.Format("{0}<br/>({1})", name, iso2)
    gvSnippets.Columns.Add(New BoundField With {.HeaderText = head, .DataField = iso2, .HtmlEncode = False})
    ... other code ...
End For
```

(My first draft did not set HtmlEncode.)

Curious observation: In my first couple of test runs, the data did not include any HTML or entities, and the HTML in the heading was NOT encoded, I got the line break and not "<br/>". Then I did a test where there were entities in the data and the entities got html-encoded ... and so did the header. So like, ASP is apparently saying that by default, if the data has no HTML but the heading does, then don't HTML-encode the heading. But if the data has HTML, then HTML-encode both the data and the heading. So like, it's deciding dynamically whether to html-encode the heading or not.

In reply to @fnostro, here's the markup for the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSnippets" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="skin3" EmptyDataText="No records found" Visible="false">
</asp:GridView>
```

There is no <Columns> markup. I build the columns completely in code. I haven't tested if the same behavior occurs in what I assume is the more normal case where you specify columns with markup.

Comment: Can you provide the `GridView` `<Columns>` markup?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code to the beginning of your loop

```
row("language") = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr("language"))
row("name") = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr("name"))
```

Comment: Hmm, how would that help. "language" and "name" contain plain text, like "English" and "EN" or "Spanish" and "ES". HtmlEncode would leave them unchanged. But this post does give me an idea. I could set HtmlEncode=false, and then do HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on the detail data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the information provided in your post I have the following suggestions:

You should isolate data formatting from raw data.

Your `DataTable` is the data source for the GridView.  The `DataTable` should contain only raw data, completely unformatted and unadulterated.

The `DataTable` gets bound to the Gridview by setting the GridView `DataSource` and making a call to `DataBind()`.  Calling `gvSnippets.Databind()` will trigger all the databinding events associated with Gridviews which will allow you to:

1. Manage simple formatting and binding in the GridView Columns in the aspx markup.
2. Handle more complicated formatting in the code behind for specific GridView events like the `RowDataBound` event.

Regarding the GridView Header:  `HeaderText` appears once at the top of the Gridview and is stored internally in `GridView.HeaderRow`, not on a per row basis even though every bound field has a HeaderText property.

---

Example excerpt gvSnippets Markup per your update:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvSnippets" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="skin3" 
    EmptyDataText="No records found" Visible="false">
  </asp:GridView>
```

Then you can do things like this in the Code Behind:

```
Public Class __JunkWebForm1
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Fill Dataset first, then:
    gvSnippets.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    ' Add Columns...
    gvSnippets.Columns.Add(...)
    gvSnippets.Columns.Add(...)
    gvSnippets.Columns.Add(...)
    . . .

    ' This will trigger data binding events
    gvSnippets.DataBind();  

  End Sub


  Private Property HeaderTextLanguage As String
  Private Property HeaderTextLanguageIso As String
  Dim NeedHeaderText As Boolean = False


  Private Sub gvSnippets_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvSnippets.DataBinding
    NeedHeaderText = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub gvSnippets_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvSnippets.DataBound
    Dim this As GridView = sender

    this.Columns(0).HeaderText = String.Format("{0}<br>({1})", HeaderTextLanguage, HeaderTextLanguageIso)
  End Sub

  Private Sub gvSnippets_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSnippets.RowDataBound
    Dim this As GridView = sender
    Dim drv As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      If NeedHeaderText Then
        HeaderTextLanguage = drv("language")
        HeaderTextLanguageIso = drv("iso")
        NeedHeaderText = False
      End If

      e.Row.Cells(0).Text = Server.HtmlEncode(drv("Somefieldnameofyours"))

    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Addendum** Dealing with Dynamic cells

For a GridView defined as:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvSnippets" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  </asp:GridView>
```

I don't know how you're populating your `ds` but I'm using a SqlDataSource to fill a table in the Code Behind.  Note there is no GridView `DataSourceID` above:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="select top 10 user_id, user_name, user_logon, 'English' as language, 'en' as iso from tbl_users" 
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>'>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in the Code Behind I can do this:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    GetDataSetAndPopulate(gvSnippets)

  End Sub

  Private Sub GetDataSetAndPopulate(gv As GridView)
    Dim view As DataView = SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
    Dim table As DataTable = view.ToTable()
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    ds.Tables.Add(table)

    For Each dc As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
        Dim field As New BoundField
        field.DataField = dc.ColumnName
        field.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName
        gv.Columns.Add(field)
    Next

    gv.DataSource = ds
    gv.DataBind()

  End Sub
```

And now the Gridview is populated dynamically and you can still handle all the formatting during the DataBinding events as needed.

Comment: Modified to reflect your Gridview definition

Comment: Something else...if you know the fieldnames are going to remain the same it's simpler to make use of the markup in the aspx.  All you're doing is defining columns with expectations of future data.  The Binding process actually ties it all together.

Comment: FYI: I was trying to skinny the question down to what's relevant to this question, but: I build the columns in code because they are different depending on data. There's a dropdown at the top of the screen where the user selects a project. For each project we have data in one or more languages, but the combination of languages is different for every project. So for project A there may be columns for English and Spanish, for project B we may have Chinese, Korean, and Japanese, etc. For each language there can be many text blocks, so there's a row for each block and a column for each language.

Comment: ok - it's important to know that column headers change based on user interaction.  But even still - Gridview can autogenerate the columns based on the bound data and you can still format in the code behind.

Comment: Updated Answer based on Empty Gridview

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I see you put a lot of effort into your answer, but ... this doesn't actually answer my question. :-0 My problem isn't how to build a GridView dynamically, but the much more specific issue of: How do I make the headings not be htmlencoded, but the data be htmlencoded. As best as I can figure out, there's one HtmlEncode parameter that applies to both headings and data.

Comment: The `HtmlEncode` property applies to Bound Fields. The header text is pulled from the Bound Field Definition, but stored in the HeaderRow which is where we overwrite the HeaderText in the DataBound Event ***after*** the binding is complete.  The HtmlEncode property does not apply at this point so format to your hearts content

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with that works in my particular case.

I am building the data to populate the GridView in code. I create a DataTable, add columns to it, and then populate those columns. Like:

```
dim dslang=GetListOfLanguages()
dim dtgv=new DataTable()
for each row as DataRow in dslang.tables(0).rows
  dim language_name=row("name")
  dim language_code=row("code")
  dtgv.columns.add(String.format("{0}<br/>({1})",language_name, language_code)
end for
... bunch of other stuff ...
... inside a loop that reads the data ...
dim outrow=dtgv.NewRow()
... get data for a specific language ...
outrow(language_code)=text
... later ...
my_gridview.datasource=dtgv
my_gridview.databind()
```

So my solution:

When creating the GridView, set HtmlEncode=false. This makes the header display correctly.

When populating the data, say

```
outrow(language_code)=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text)
```

So I add the data to the datatable that will ultimately be used as the datasource for the gridview already encoded, so I don't need to rely on the Gridview encoding it.

I consider this a mediocre solution, as it only works because I am populating GridView from a DataTable that I build with code. If I was populating the GridView directly from a DataSource specified in markup, or from a DataSet created by a database query, there'd be no convenient place to put the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode call.